# Is atmosphere a concrete or abstract noun?

Tags: nouns

It can be sensed, obviously but its tangibility is often elusive. It is not something which necessarily be directly perceived, more a combination of factors.

Answer (score 1):

## Both. It depends on what you mean.

Atmosphere has two meanings, one abstract and one concrete. [OED link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/atmosphere)

> 1. The envelope of gases surrounding the earth or another planet.

This is a **concrete** noun. It refers to something that **physically exists**. Whether it has a solid, liquid or gaseous state does not matter. All that matters is that it exists in the physical realm.

> 2. The pervading tone or mood of a place, situation, or creative work.

This is an **abstract** noun. It refers to something that **does not physically exist**, it is only an idea in our minds.

---

I think you're confusing tangibility (in the sense of a concrete noun) with the ability to physically touch and interact with something. Look at the [definition of "tangible"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tangible):

> 1. Perceptible by touch.
>
> 1.1 Clear and definite; real.

You're thinking of definition 1. (related to physical touch), but you should actually be thinking of definition 1.1 (real, not abstract)

---

[I found the following definition online](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/abstract-nouns/), which encapsulates the idea better than I've managed to phrase it:

> **Abstract** nouns are words that name things that are not concrete. Your five physical senses cannot detect an abstract noun – you can't see it, smell it, taste it, hear it, or touch it. In essence, an abstract noun is a quality, a concept, an idea, or maybe even an event.